# wired internet stops working after install VPN in windows on dual boot pc

Tags: networking

I have a dual boot dell 5810 with windows and elementery os on different physical drives. everything was fine until i installed vpn on the windows installation. now my wired internet in elementery says it is connected but no data comes through; no pages can load in the browser and app centre cannot find repositories. 
i can still connect to the internet as normal from the windows installation so i don't think it is hardware.
can anyone give some suggestions on how to get it working again ?,

i tried uninstalling the vpn in windows, but elementery still won't connect